# Sort by date and time for nonblank cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I sort or filter in ascending order by date and time, ignoring any blank rows?

Goal is to have earliest date and time displayed first ie (5/3/22 5:00 before 5/3/22 6:00 before 5/3/23 5:00 etc.)

I should note that my data has been compiled using a query that combined two separate sheets, and while the original values for data time (mm/dd/yyyy xx:xx:xx) displays aligned right of the cell in the source sheets, after the query it appears displayed on the left (as in the table below)

I tried adapting 2 of the solutions suggested in another [post][1] `=SORT(FILTER(sheet1!A2:L100;ISTEXT(sheet1!D2:D100));4;TRUE)` and `QUERY(sheet1!A2:L100;"select * where D != '' order by D";0)` but they did not work.

My adapted formulas were =`SORT(FILTER(A2:A,ISTEXT(A2:A)),4,TRUE)` and then I adapted my original query which also combined two sheets:

`QUERY({'Sheet1'!A2:B;'Sheet2'!A2:B},"select * where Col1 <>'' order by Col1";0)`

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2/15/2021 16:50:03 | 1 |
| 5/3/2021 14:22:01 | 2 |
| 4/21/2020 23:34:56 | 3 |
| 4/29/2021 20:10:14 | 4 |
| 5/31/2021 14:31:42 | 5 |
| 8/4/2021 21:32:45 | 6 |
| 9/14/2021 11:20:02 | 7 |
| 10/11/2021 17:09:53 | 8 |
| 12/15/2021 15:48:48 | 9 |
| 1/12/2022 19:31:41 | 10 |
| 2/9/2022 18:08:50 | 11 |
| 3/9/2022 18:44:03 | 12 |
| 4/6/2022 18:58:24 | 13 |
| 6/29/2021 3:35:33 | 14 |
| 6/9/2021 17:00:32 | 15 |
| 8/2/2020 18:10:24 | 16 |
| 6/7/2020 19:56:28 | 17 |
| 6/29/2020 19:27:26 | 18 |
| 7/16/2020 15:47:57 | 19 |
| 9/16/2020 18:59:34 | 20 |
| 10/19/2020 18:46:30 | 21 |
| 11/18/2020 20:23:47 | 22 |
| 1/13/2021 23:27:38 | 23 |
| 2/10/2021 20:08:00 | 24 |
| 4/14/2021 19:30:09 | 25 |
| 8/12/2021 11:37:00 | 26 |
|  |  |

I think its possible it has something to do with the value formatting but I'm not sure.
[1]: [How to sort only those rows which have no blank cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052836/how-to-sort-only-those-rows-which-have-no-blank-cell)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** If you cannot change the format of the imported source data and your timestamps are coming in as plain text, you can...

**1. Create a 3rd column to convert the imported plain text timestamps to proper timestamps** with the following:

```
=BYROW($A$2:$A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",JOIN(" ",SPLIT(r," "))-0)))
```

where you can substitute `$A$2:$A` for whatever column your plaintext timestamps are landing after import. If you are importing data into different tabs you simply do this in each import tab in, say, Column C:C.

*This looks wonky but it works because after a split the date chunk is auto-formatted as a date value and the time chunk is auto-formatted as a time value. When you join them back together it results in proper Date time value.*

**2. Grab the range with those new values (and rearrange the outputs, if needed)** with something like the following (if the converted date times are in Sheet1!C:C and Sheet2!C:C):

```
=QUERY({Sheet2!B2:C;Sheet3!B2:C},
  "SELECT Col2,Col1 
   WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
   ORDER BY Col2 ASC",0)
```

Comment: I get #value error. If I add "date" in front of Col 1. But according to Ben Collins, I would need to modify inside the query in a format similar to the following: query(Data!$A$1:$H$136,"select C, B where B > date '"&text(G7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1). How is the formula provided, modified in that way?

Comment: Also will this be able to filter by time also?

Comment: Also to filter by date and time I think will need select A
= datetime ‘” & text(A2, “yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss”) & “‘”

Comment: @MMsmithH [this resource](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-filter-timestamp-in-query-in-google-sheets/) might help you out. Looks like instead of `date ‘“&text(G7,”yyyy-mm-dd”)` you add `datetime ‘“&text(G7,”yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss”)`

Comment: Haha yep, exactly—you got to it on your own as I was typing response. Does that work?

Comment: No because, I am working with an array or range not a single cell (G7). Can you show me how you would modify this: QUERY(
{'Sheet1'!A2:B;'Sheet2'!A2:B},"
SELECT *
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Col1 ASC”,0) and then I shall select you answer as the winner! But maybe edit the answer to include the solution.

Comment: Mind sharing an example copy of your sheet here? Also, are you located in the US? Formula syntax may vary based on locale

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1868uRfJA8MgtCEec3xIZqli8UJvpWZNb3mYUb3uhCEY

Comment: See new answer—it's much simpler than we were making it out to be :)

Comment: Still does not work in my use actual use case, where it was imported, I reproduced this in the shared sheet.  See test, sheet5 and sheet6. For whatever reason when the source is imported from another location it doesnt work (probably because even after setting day time, the values still inherrit some of the original formatting)

Comment: When I changed the format of Sheet1!A:A to `Date time` it works, but I’m guess you cannot change the format of the source file…

Comment: @MMsmithH ok see NEW new answer—I think we've got it now :)

Comment: @MMsmithH any luck with the updated answer?

Comment: sorry, busy on another task for past week but will come back to this later.